# How to generate bivariate categorical variables with defined correlation?

Tags: r

Suppose I have two categorical variables `A` and `B` and both have three levels, `1, 2, 3` with prob `0.2`, `0.3`, and `0.5` for each level. How could I generate a list of random bivariate data of A and B with defined correlation 0.3? I know for a univariate A or B we can do

```
A=sample(1:3, 100, T, prob=c(0.2,0.3,0.5))
B=sample(1:3, 100, T, prob=c(0.2,0.3,0.5))
```

My question is how to sample `cbind(A,B)` with `cor(A,B)=0.3`?

Comment: Do you want to treat A and B as continuous when calculating correlation? Or what measure of correlation do you want to use for discrete/categorical data? Are you assuming ordinal data?

Comment: Just assume a Pearson's correlation.

Comment: Just define the joint probability matrix yourself. From there, sampling is very straightforward.

Comment: Thanks, @Frank. May you please provide a brief answer+1?

Comment: see [this article](http://www.sitmo.com/article/generating-correlated-random-numbers/)

Comment: Well... you only get a one to many select in this case. Maybe. The correlation between these vectors could be anything. Interesting question, I'd define the probability structure first and then sample from that.

Comment: Determining the probability matrix consistent with given marginal probabilities and a correlation isn't really a programming problem (what Stack Overflow is designed to handle). If you're not sure how to do that, maybe you'll find another site is a better place to ask. I tried to answer the "How to sample once you've got a matrix" question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example probability matrix. (Your own will depend on your chosen model.)

```
# describe probabilities over the space by a matrix
set.seed(1)
nA <- 3
nB <- 3
probmat <- matrix({r<-runif(nA*nB);r/sum(r)},ncol=nB)
#            [,1]       [,2]      [,3]
# [1,] 0.04868724 0.16654119 0.1732284
# [2,] 0.06823764 0.03698311 0.1211728
# [3,] 0.10504609 0.16474081 0.1153628
```

And here's one way to draw samples from it:

```
# rearrange
probs  <- c(probmat)
events <- as.matrix(expand.grid(A=1:nA,B=1:nB))

# draw samples
nSamp  <- 100
samp   <- events[sample.int(nA*nB,nSamp,prob=probs,replace=TRUE),]
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is equivalent R code for [this artical](http://www.sitmo.com/article/generating-correlated-random-numbers/) with a matlab example.  You can use apply `pnorm()` and `cut()` to the columns the get correlated discrete random variables

```
# parameters
nrows  <-  10

# The desired correlation matrix
(M  <-    matrix(c(1.0,0.6,0.3,
                  0.6,1.0,0.5,
                  0.3,0.5,1.0),byrow=T,ncol=3))


#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]  1.0  0.6  0.3
#> [2,]  0.6  1.0  0.5
#> [3,]  0.3  0.5  1.0

(U = chol(M))
#>      [,1] [,2]      [,3]
#> [1,]    1  0.6 0.3000000
#> [2,]    0  0.8 0.4000000
#> [3,]    0  0.0 0.8660254 

# generate a random matrix where columns have the desired correlatoin structure
matrix(rnorm(nrows*ncol(M)),ncol=ncol(M))%*%U

#>   -0.4326   -0.4089    0.0505
#>   -1.6656   -0.4187   -1.3665
#>    0.1253   -0.3955    0.4209
#>    0.2877    1.9192    2.3656
#>   -1.1465   -0.7970   -0.9976
#>    1.1909    0.8057    1.1459
#>    1.1892    1.5669    1.8695
#>   -0.0376    0.0248   -1.3678
#>    0.3273    0.1199   -1.1880
#>    0.1746   -0.5611    0.2141


# check that this works
cor(matrix(rnorm(1000000*ncol(M)),ncol=ncol(M))%*%U)

#>           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
#> [1,] 1.0000000 0.5988445 0.2987633
#> [2,] 0.5988445 1.0000000 0.4992603
#> [3,] 0.2987633 0.4992603 1.0000000
```

Comment: Thanks, @Jthorpe! But I would the variables are categorical or ordinal.  some solution for that?